# Django and root processes

Tags: python, django, django-views, root, ping

In my Django project I need to be able to check whether a host on the LAN is *up* using an ICMP ping. I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316866/ping-a-site-in-python) which answers how to ping something in Python and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767841/using-celery-in-a-django-app-to-run-script-with-root-priviliges) which links to resources explaining how to use the sodoers file.

#### The Setting

A `Device` model stores an IP address for a host on the LAN, and after adding a new `Device` instance to the DB (via a custom view, not the admin) I envisage checking to see if the device responds to a ping using an AJAX call to an API which exposes the capability.

#### The Problem

However (from the docstring of a library suggested in the the first SO question) "Note that ICMP messages can only be sent from processes running as root."

I don't want to run Django as the root user, since it is bad practice. However this part of the process (sending and ICMP ping) needs to run as root. If with a Django view I wish to send off a ping packet to test the liveness of a host then Django itself is required to be running as root since that is the process which would be invoking the ping.

#### Solutions

These are the solutions I can think of, and **my question is are there any better ways to only execute select parts of a Django project as root**, other than these:

1. Run Django as root (please no!)
2. Put a "ping request" in a queue that another processes -- run as root -- can periodically check and fulfil. Maybe something like [celery](http://ask.github.com/celery/getting-started/introduction.html).

### Is there not a simpler way?

I want something like a "Django run as root" library, is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely no way, do not run the Django code as root!

I would run a daemon as root (written in Python, why not) and then [IPC](http://docs.python.org/library/ipc.html) between the Django instance and your daemon. As long as you're sure to validate the content and properly handle it (e.g. use `subprocess.call` with  an array etc) and only pass in data (not commands to execute) it should be fine.

Here is an example client and server, using web.py

Server: http://gist.github.com/788639
Client: http://gist.github.com/788658

You'll need to install webpy.org but it's worth having around anyway. If you can hard-wire the IP (or hostname) into the server and remove the argument, all the better.

Comment: Could you give an example of how IPC would be used from the Django view in order to talk to the daemon, I have little experience with subprocess.

Comment: Sure, if I have time on the bus home!

Comment: @Marcus: Here's a simple server: http://gist.github.com/788639 and here's a simple client: http://gist.github.com/788658 . You'll need to install http://webpy.org/ but it's worth having around anyway. If you can hard-wire the IP (or hostname) into the server and remove the argument, all the better. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

What's your OS here? You might be able to write a little program that does what you want given a parameter, and stick that in the sudoers file, and give your django user permission to run it as root.

/etc/sudoers

Comment: Primarily Ubuntu, but my intent is to be as cross-platform as possible as far as it is non-troublesome. How would you give Django permission in the context of your solution?

Comment: django runs as a user (wwwuser maybe?), so you'd give that user permission to run ping (or whatever) as root. Then subprocess executes "sudo ping [ip]" - that should work... Sorry can't give a concrete example. Write a test script to run outside of Django, su to the wwwuser and test...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kind of system you're on, but on any box I've encountered, one does not have to be root to run the command-line `ping` program (it has the suid bit set, so it becomes root as necessary). So you could just invoke that. It's a bit more overhead, but probably negligible compared to network latency.

Comment: So your saying that `subprocess.popen('ping', address)` would do the trick. However I might be doing other things in the future that *would* require root privileges in the fashion described.