# Giving django app root access?

Tags: python, django, root, sudo

I am trying to build an api using django which should alter iptables using POST parameters. I am using django 1.4, [djangorestframework](http://django-rest-framework.org/), [python-iptables](https://github.com/ldx/python-iptables). The problem I am facing is that python-iptables need root access to change iptables rules. I can change the iptables rules by doing `$ sudo python` and from the python shell I can change those rules. Also I can change those rules by using [iptdump](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iptdump) module which takes in iptables parameters and create those rules which I can later save in a file (iptables.rules.txt) and use fabric's `local('sudo iptables-restore < iptables.rules.txt')`. But this will always prompt the user for a root password. Is there a way I can give django app root privileges so that I can bypass sudo password prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really need a part of the application to run as root, you could rewrite it as a daemon, and communicate with it from the main Django application as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4749073/2248275). I would only recommend it if the alternative below does not suit your requirements.

The alternative `sudo iptables-restore < iptables.rules.txt` is much simpler, just tell sudo not to ask for the password for just this command by adding this to your **/etc/sudoers** file:

```
djangouser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iptables-restore
```

Where `djangouser` is the user the Django process is running as.

**EDIT:** You can avoid writing an intermediate file by sending the new iptables directly to the `iptables-restore` process:

```
import iptdump
import subprocess

ipt = iptdump.Iptables()
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', '/sbin/iptables-restore'],
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate(ipt.dump())
```

Comment: hey thanks this works but is there a way that I can bypass sudo password prompt.

Comment: @Saad the line in **/etc/sudoers** should prevent the password prompt, are you sure the code is running as the user specified in sudoers?